# order of an element in a modulo group under multiplication

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

Suppose $G$ is the group $ℤ_{37}^\times$ under multiplication.

Then is there a way that I can prove the order of the element $2$ in $G$ is $36$ without finding all the powers of $2$ until I get unity?

Answer (score 2):

Lagrange's theorem says you only have to check $2^2,2^3,2^4,2^6,2^9,2^{12}$ and $2^{18}$. The checking itself is a lot easier if you exploit relations like $2^6\cdot 2^3=2^9$ and $(2^6)^2=2^{12}$.

Comment: And you can even get away with only checking $2^{36/p}$ for every prime $p$ that divides $36$ -- that is, $2^{12}$ and $2^{18}$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm That's theoretically simpler, but difficult to do without calculating most of the rest as subcalculations.

Comment: Well, it's just smallish powers of $2$ -- you don't need to reduce each of them modulo $37$ but can go directly to $4096 \bmod 37$. And then multiply that by $64$ and reduce once again, and you're done. (And even if the candidate generator wasn't $2$, one wouldn't have to calculate $a^4$ and $a^9$).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by the Order Test below, $\,2\,$ has order $36\iff 2^{12}\neq 1\neq 2^{ 18}$

**Order Test** $\,\ \,a\,$ has order $\,n\iff a^n \equiv 1\,$ but $\,a^{n/p} \not\equiv 1\,$ for every prime $\,p\mid n.\,$

**Proof** $\ (\Leftarrow)\ $ If $\,a\,$ has $\,\rm\color{#c00}{order\ k}\,$ then $\,k\mid n.\,$  If $\,k < n\,$ then $\,k\,$ is *proper* divisor of $\,n\,$ therefore $\,k\,$ must omit at least one prime $\,p\,$ from the unique prime factorization of $\,n,\,$ hence $\,k\mid n/p,\,$ say $\, kj = n/p,\,$ so $\,a^{n/p} \equiv (\color{#c00}{a^k})^j\equiv \color{#c00}1^j\equiv 1,\,$ contra hypothesis. $\ (\Rightarrow)\ $ By definition of order.